# how to make a dynamic group of filter for every group of product in LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-entities

i have some Group of *PRODUCTS* that every Group has a Group OF *FILTER ATTRIBUTE* and its dynamic for every Groups now I want to Users could Choose multiple Filter for every Group Foreexample Group of brand and color that choosed 2 brand and 3 color that 2 brand are union itself and also 3 color should be union but combination of these two Group of Filters should be intersect

i found a solution but I think is amateur

```
for (var i = 0; i < filtA.Length; i++)
                    {
                        eachfiltGrp = filtA[i].Split('G');
                        eachfilt = eachfiltGrp[1].Split('A');

                        if (eachfilt.Length == 1)
                        {
                            var filter0 = Convert.ToInt32(eachfilt[0]);
                            products = products.Include(p => p.Product_Attribut).Where(x => x.Product_Attribut.Any(p => p.AttributeID == filter0));

                        }
                        else if (eachfilt.Length == 2)
                        {
                            var filter0 = Convert.ToInt32(eachfilt[0]);
                            var filter1 = Convert.ToInt32(eachfilt[1]);
                            products = products.Include(p => p.Product_Attribut).Where(x => x.Product_Attribut.Any(p => p.AttributeID == filter0 || p.AttributeID == filter1));
                        }
                        else if (eachfilt.Length == 3)
                        {
                            var filter0 = Convert.ToInt32(eachfilt[0]);
                            var filter1 = Convert.ToInt32(eachfilt[1]);
                            var filter2 = Convert.ToInt32(eachfilt[2]);
                            products = products.Include(p => p.Product_Attribut).Where(x => x.Product_Attribut.Any(p => p.AttributeID == filter0 || p.AttributeID == filter1 || p.AttributeID == filter2));
                        }
```

this works perfectly but just for 3 group of filters and for more i should write more condition 
here *filterA* has string including all filters sent to controller and every Group id and the filters splited by *G* and eachfilter for a group splited by *A* thst is not dynamic

now i change these lines with this and sounds it should  work

```
   var products = db.Products.Include(p => p.Product_Groups);


    for (var i = 0; i < filtA.Length; i++)
                        {
                            eachfiltGrp = filtA[i].Split('G');
                            eachfilt = eachfiltGrp[1].Split('A');
                            products = Products.Where(p => p.Product_Attribut.Any(x => eachfilt.Contains(x.AttributeID.ToString())));

                         }
```

this work good but just only for the last loop that means the last filter Group sent to controller affect on product and not the rest

any suggestion for this?

Comment: That's because you are declaring productsFilter var each time inside your loop. Take it outside the loop and then just filter it inside

Comment: @arunKumar no no Tnq I just wrote the wrong code for before but this edited code also not working

Comment: then you need to create a filter array separately and then use that in one go

Comment: i know this could be possible but whenever i do this i should intersect last array and current and this not possible because they are not a list to intersect them and i want to send them after all to pagedlist and .net dont allow me to this , if you have any suggestion can u write it as a solution? @ArunKumar

Comment: Define the variables at the place you use them (similar to `filter0`, `filter1` etc). Currently in your last attempt most likely you have closure issue. Remove the declaration of the `eachfilt` variable where is now in the code (not shown), add `var ` here `eachfilt = ….` and the issue will be solved.

Comment: @IVANSTOEV Tnq worked Perfectly